# Notification ID does not change

Tags: android

Hi guys I have implemented notification feature. 
I have a problem with notify ID.

This is my code:

```
protected void ShowNotification(String title, String text){

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atterrato)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(text)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(text));

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
mBuilder.build();
}
```

I do not want to replace a notification.

I want increment the 0, but I don't know how solve this.
If I declare a variable and I destroy the activity doesn't work...
Is there a simple method for solve this?

Using getSharedPreference?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using SharedPreferences? Sounds like it would work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on continuously incrementing a number, your best bet would be to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

First you need want to have an initialization for it:

```
private void sharedPrefsInit()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Number", 0);

    // This if statement checks if the number has been accessed before
    if(sharedPrefs.getInt("MyNum", -1) == -1)
    {
        // If it hasn't, create it
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

        editor.putInt("MyNum", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

If you put the above method in your `onCreate()`, it will guarantee that you're accessing the right thing.  Now you'll want to create a small method that increments your number for you and you're all set.  It'll probably look like this.

```
private int incMyNum()
{
    int newNum;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Number", 0);

    newNum = sharedPrefs.getInt("MyNum", -1);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    editor.putInt("MyNum", ++newNum);
    editor.commit();

    return newNum;
}
```

Now your `showNotification()` method can have this

```
notificationManager.notify(incMyNum(), mBuilder.build());
```